# CLR Proc calling a Web API causing Timeout errors

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, sqlclr, database-trigger

I have googled enough and I just cannot get past this error. I have an INSERT trigger (Non-CLR, SQL Server 2014) which collects all rows from the Inserted table and moves it to a @temp table (datatype table)  as the first step. I next call the SQL CLR Proc from within a while loop of this @temp table(Once per row).

The C# CLR proc in turn calls an API that I have written. There are no issues absolutely so far, as the calls from my CLR proc does reach the API in a matter of milliseconds. From within the first API method, I do a SELECT on the tables that exist on the same DB as the trigger (and the CLR proc). That returns rows almost instantly. So, all is fine until now.

But when I try to update the row on the same table for which I have written the INSERT trigger, it just times out. If I move the same logic of the trigger into an non-CLR proc and call the CLR proc from within this non-CLR proc, it works like a charm! I still fail to understand how different is a trigger than a stored proc.

Can you please let me know what I am missing? It's got nothing to do with the while loop inside the trigger, as I am just testing with one row for now and I still get the timeout. It has something to do with an UPDATE statement fired on the same table on which I am looping through.

I also think it has to do with the fact that the CLR proc has the 'context connection=true' BUT the API, I am opening a separate ADO.NET connection and SQlReader etc.

I can't narrow it down to the cause. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: sounds like you created an infinite loop.  You have a trigger on a table.  It wont update till it gets results from a CLR that does an out of process update on the same table from a different connection which then kicks off the trigger that will call the same CLR and another out of process update.  The cycle continues because it would never return to the process calling the clr originally.  It seems like there would be a way better way of updating.  If you really need something out of process return the value to be updated back to the trigger and update there not in the clr/other proc

Comment: Are you opening a separate ADO.NET connection for your update? If so, I wonder if you are not being blocked by the insert process.

Comment: Thanks much for your quick replies. Matt, the trigger is After INSERT and I am Updating  the row.  That is where I fail to understand as the columns I am updating are completely different than the ones I am interested in within the trigger. There are no UPDATE triggers.

Comment: Niels Berglund, thank you for your response. Yes, I am opening a separate ADO.NET connection from within the API. So, basically I call my CLR proc as thus:WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Temp)

Comment: WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Temp)

Comment: EXEC [ppt].[CLR_sp_ProcessRequest] '@param1, @Param2'


and since it is an Web API  that I am calling, I can't use the context connection string and so from within the API, 

 using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(.DecodeConnectionString()))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                var trans = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();

                using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(spName, sqlConnection, trans))

---UPDATE TWO DIFFERENT COLUMNS BUT FOR THE SAME INSERTED ROW THE TRIGGER FIRED

Comment: Sorry, it didn't allow me to include @ in the comment more than once. But I have it all correct here.  I don't think there is any infinite loop. It has to be a lock of some sorts or something of that nature.

Comment: The problem I have is due to my access rights, I can't run the profiler. With the limited access I have, it kinda didn't show me the true effects of the CLR proc.

Comment: @Ram_P Please do not post code in comments. Please update the question text to include the additional info / code blocks. Also, if you need to post code snippets in comments, enclose the code in back-ticks that will format the text as `code` which will allow for `@at signs` galore :-). Outside of code snippets, at signs are used as "mentions" to notify someone that there is a comment for them, if they aren't the person who posted the Question or Answer that the comment is on, and are limited to 1 per comment.

Comment: Solomon, just saw this message. Got it:-). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you cannot run SQL Server Profiler, you should be able to `SELECT` from `sys.dm_exec_requests`. Doing that you should see that the second Session (the one created by the external / non-"Context Connection" connection) is being blocked by the original Session that had issued the `INSERT` statement. Triggers exist within a system-initiated Transaction, and the row is locked. Your external connection in the API call doing the `UPDATE` is another Session that cannot gain write-access to that row until the initial Session (the one executing the `INSERT`) is completes its Transaction, yet that cannot happen because it is waiting on the external connection to complete, yet that cannot happen due to the initial row being locked, and around the circle again and again.

You will need to either move the `UPDATE` statement to out of the API call and into the SQLCLR Stored Procedure or the Trigger, OR handle the API call asynchronously so that it is not initiated by the `INSERT` Trigger.

Also, why do you create a Transaction within the API call? Are you updating the two columns on the same row in two separate `SqlCommand` executions? If so, why not make them a single `UPDATE` statement and get rid of the explicit Transaction?

Comment: Thank You Solomon. I am going to try that out now. It makes so much sense what you have written here. But  It is pretty weird that I copy the same exact code from the trigger, including the While Loop and the call to the CLR proc, into a non-CLR stored proc  and it works!  The only difference being instead of reading the rows from the inserted table, I read the set of rows based on a timestamp.   There are no timeouts then. I am only struggling to understand why an 'AFTER INSERT'  trigger may block a row but  the same code in a stored proc does not. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ram_P As I mentioned, the Trigger itself exists within a system-initiated Transaction. This ensures that whatever is being inserted will will either `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` along with whatever is being done in the Trigger, since it is part of the `INSERT` itself, not a separate action. That Transaction locks the row(s) being inserted until the Trigger completes, which in this case, cannot happen as something that the Trigger is calling -- the API call doing the `UPDATE` -- is being blocked by the `INSERT`. Also, code snippets in comments (and in questions and answers), use back-ticks, not `'`.

Comment: I did run the sys.dm_exec_requests that you had mentioned.  I had honestly never heard of that command before and it took me a while to analyze what those results meant.  I learnt a lot thanks to all your replies, especially yours @Solomon.  I will try out a bit more, tomorrow and then  close this thread. Thanks again.